# Select row if sub string exist in column otherwise select all rows

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to select records from an Access 2010 query based on whether the text in the field contains a sub string.  However, if the sub string does not exist it should return all of the rows in the query.


For example, Given the following records:

```
User      Fruit
----      -----

Fred      Apple
George    Banana
Mary      Apple
Mike      Pear
John      Pear
```

If 'Apple' specified in the SQL WHERE clause I would expect the records returned to be:

```
User      Fruit
----      -----

Fred      Apple
Mary      Apple
```

If Not 'Apple' specified in the SQL WHERE clause I would expect the records returned to be:

```
User      Fruit
----      -----

George    Banana
Mike      Pear
John      Pear
```

This seems to be such a simple query and would prefer to apply the criteria to just a single field (i.e. Fruit) as actual query is quite complex. However, I just can't get it to do an exclusive or i.e. one or the other but not both.

Regards

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is the "query" you are referring to?  How is "Apple" in a query?

Comment: Query can more explicitly stated as the SQL criteria used i.e. in this case I'm referring to the SQL WHERE clause criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that, i suppose:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE FRUIT = 'Apple' OR 0 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE FRUIT = 'Apple')
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail this has given me the exact answer to the question posed.  Having tested it and seen the results I have realised unfortunately this is not what I actually want :( .  Not sure if I'll have to reformulate the question here...or post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Fruit='Apple') THEN
     SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Fruit='Apple'
 ELSE
     SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Fruit!='Apple'
 END IF
```